# How to compare time in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

In Freemarker, I can use `.now?time` to get the current time, but how do I compare that to another time?

For example, how would I properly test if the current time is between 8:00 AM and 5:00 PM?

```
<#if .now?time gte (?) && .now?time lte (?)>
  //do something
<#/if>
```

I don't know what to put in the (?) because I'm not sure how to create date scalars in Freemarker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can compare two `java.util.Date`-s as far as they are both of the same kind (like both are time-only values), then it's up to you to ensure that the internal representations are consistent (like a time-only value is in the epoch-day VS on some other day). Thus it's mostly meant to be used for comparing date-time values (timestamps) where no such issue exists. So, since you know that you want an epoch-based time, you could do the following hack:

```
<#assign nowTime = .now?time?string.iso?time.iso>
```

Now it's correctly comparable with `"8:00:00 AM"?time`, however, I recommend using ISO format, because the locale-specific format is kind of fragile (like if you change locale, it won't work): `'08:00:00'?time.iso`. Note that for this you need at least FreeMarker 2.3.21.

Answer (score 2):

I read the source of freemarker 2.3.21 and found that  current freemarker does not support comparing `.now?time` and time object such as `"8:00:00 AM"?time`.

That is because`.now?time` is internally treated as current time such as `2014-10-21 15:11:30`,
and `"8:00:00 AM"?time` is treated as `1970-01-01 08:00:00`.

Therefore, `<#if .now?time gte "8:00:00 AM"?time >` is always true.

If you think it's a bug you may report to http://sourceforge.net/p/freemarker/bugs/ or send a question in freemarker's mailing list.

So the current workaround is to create the `Date` object and compare it in the java code.

Comment: FreeMarker only deals with formatting aspects as far as possible. The usual expectation is that if date-time `${dt}` prints something like `2014-10-21 15:11:30`, then `${dt?time}` prints `15:11:30`. Yet, the Java value of the object shouldn't change, especially as Java doesn't define a time type (prior Java 8 at least).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use **Liferay** you can try the ***compareTo()*** function:

It returns negative if the date is earlier, positive if it is later and zero if they are equal.

```
<#assign time1 = "11:55:00"?time>
<#assign time2 = "11:56:00"?time>

${dateUtil.compareTo(time1, time2)} <#-- Return -1 -->
${dateUtil.compareTo(time2, time1)} <#-- Return  1 -->
${dateUtil.compareTo(time1, time1)} <#-- Return  0 -->
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to the documentation on `dateUtil`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Sure, I usually look at the [liferay api](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.2-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/index.html?com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/DateUtil.html) or view the code directly through [github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/DateUtil.java)

Comment: You didn't mention Liferay in your answer nor was it mentioned by the OP. In plain FreeMarker `dateUtil` will not be available.

Comment: Oh, you're right and I hadn't noticed before answering, my bad